# Laravel pagination Links not working on queries

Tags: php, validation, laravel, input, laravel-blade

I have this search engine with some advanced search options but I get errors when I use advance options.

When I go to the next pages I see errors.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
$Input    = Input::all();
$makethis = Input::flash();

$items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=', Input::get('sex'))
                 ->paginate(6);

return View::make('gamefarms/index', compact('items', 'makethis'));
```

For my views

```
@foreach(array_chunk($items->all(), 3) as $row)
  <div class="row">

    @foreach ($row as $item)
      <div class="col-md-4">

        <h2>{{ $item->bname}}</h2>
        <img src="{{$item->img_loc}}">
        <div>{{$item->desc}}</div>

      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>

@endforeach

{{ $items->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

Comment: I got errors mainly on the links part

Comment: What exactly are the errors you get?  What advanced options?

Comment: its Error Code: 405 sir

Comment: i got this url on the error http://localhost/laravel/public/show?_token=ugDbO50dSc6ODlOltGItQ9Plm9SNtr4k30gamnbd&wband=&soptions=breed&sex=0&page=2

Answer (score 0):

```
return View::make('gamefarms/index',compact('items','makethis'))->with('items',$items);
```

Comment: there is no issue about this sir, the error is about the pagination links

Comment: `{{$items->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}` you are calling the variable `items` but you haven't sent it to the page.

Comment: it in the compact items

Comment: got this url on the error 
http://localhost/laravel/public/show?_token=ugDbO50dSc6ODlOltGItQ9Plm9SNtr4k30gamnbd&wband=&soptions=breed&sex=0&page=2

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: this is an answer to his mistake @insomniac